# How can I get form field values to sum up to another field value using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html form fields that I need the sum of acct1, acct2 and acct3 to equal the value of the surcharge field.

```
<input type="text" name="surcharge" id="surcharge" class="gui-input" placeholder="xx.xx">

<input type="text" name="acct1" id="acct1" placeholder="xx.xx">
<input type="text" name="acct2" id="acct2" placeholder="xx.xx">
<input type="text" name="acct3" id="acct3" placeholder="xx.xx">
```

I have tried several variations of this thus far:

```
$('#surcharge').change(function(){
    if( ( $('#acct1').val() + $('#acct2').val() + $('#acct3').val() ) == $('#surcharge') ){
        alert("Values match Surcharge");
    }
    else {
        alert("Values DO NOT match Surcharge");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to call `parseInt` method on each field value, like this `var acct1Val = $('#acct1').val();  parseInt(acct1Val) + ......;`

Comment: What am I missing here?  The OP's input fields suggest these are supposed to be decimals, not integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `val()` method returns a string. It needs to be converted to an integer first. You can do that by calling `Number()` and wrapping the value inside the parentheses.

```
$('#surcharge').change(function(){
    if( Number($('#acct1').val()) + Number($('#acct2').val()) + Number($('#acct3').val()) == $('#surcharge').val() ){
        alert("Values match Surcharge");
    }
    else {
        alert("Values DO NOT match Surcharge");
    }
});
```

This is kind of tough to read though, so might be a better idea to break it down

```
$('#surcharge').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#acct1", "#acct2", "#acct3").each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    if (total == $('surcharge').val()) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast the value to integer

```
parseInt($('#acct1').val())+parseInt($('#acct2').val());
```

Comment: Won't this drop the decimals?

Comment: It will drop the decimals

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you field values to numbers. The default input field value is a string. At the moment you are adding strings. To get a number do this for all your fields (including surcharge):

```
parseFloat($('#acct1').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#surcharge,#acct1,#acct2,#acct3').keyup(function() {
      console.log([parseInt($('#acct1').val()),parseInt($('#acct2').val()),parseInt($('#acct3').val()), parseInt($('#surcharge').val())]);
        if (
          (
            parseInt($('#acct1').val()) + parseInt($('#acct2').val()) + parseInt($('#acct3').val())
          ) == parseInt(
            $('#surcharge').val()
          )
        ) {
          alert("Values match Surcharge");
        } else {
          alert("Values DO NOT match Surcharge");
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="acct1" value="1">+
<input id="acct2" value="1">+
<input id="acct3" value="1">=
<input id="surcharge" value="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your listener to something like blur so the event doesn't trigger with every change (key press) on the surcharge field.

Also, add a class to all of your acct input fields so you can loop by the class:

```
$( "#surcharge" ).blur(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".acct").each(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
   //you may want total.toFixed(2)
   if(parseFloat($(this).val()) == total.toFixed(2)) {
    alert("Values match Surcharge");  
   } else {
    alert("boooo!");
   }

});
```

And here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5bzunnx/2/) demo.